# MapKit: Bad access on CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

Here is my crash

[image]

The crash address is either `0x00000000` or `0x00000001` or sometimes even `0x00000002`

[image]

[image]

Im getting a crash while woking with Map Kit.  I am adding a large amount of overlays to the map from a database.  This crash looks like its related to drawing the actual overlay onto the map.  I am adding MKPolyLines in the usual way.

```
MKPolyline* pathOverlay = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:pathIndex];
free(locations);
[overlays addObject:pathOverlay];
...
[self.mapView addOverlays:overlays];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I can post more code if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Iv checked for zero points `NSAssert(latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0...` also for identical adjacent points.  Neither have worked.

Comment: Also posted this in the Apple developer forums  https://devforums.apple.com/thread/176674?tstart=0